# How can I run a virtualenv python script as a git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, virtualenv

This is my pre-commit script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in .git/hooks/pre-commit.d/*; do
    if [ -x "$f" ]; then
        if ! "$f"; then
            echo "DID NOT COMMIT YOUR CHANGES!";
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done
```

One of the executables in pre-commit.d is a python script (pre-commit-pylint.py) that starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pylint
```

pylint is installed on my virtualenv. My problem is that git runs pre-commit prepending `/usr/libexec/git-core:/usr/bin` to `$PATH`, so even if my virtualenv is activated the `pre-commit.d/pre-commit-pylint.py` script runs with the system `/usr/bin/python` (instead of running with the virtualenv python).

I want to have hooks that are compatible for developers that are not using virtualenv. Is there any way to run my python script with virtualenv transparently (ie, staying compatible with developers that are using their system python)?

Comment: did you ever find a way to prevent Git from prepending `/usr/bin` to the hook's $PATH? Just encountered this myself.

Comment: no, I didn't. I worked around my problem with Rob's answer.

Comment: same for Ruby's rbenv: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/374

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check in your pre-commit script for the $VIRTUAL_ENV variable and prepend it to $PATH accordingly:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n $VIRTUAL_ENV ]; then
    PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH
fi

for f in .git/hooks/pre-commit.d/*; do
    if [ -x "$f" ]; then
        if ! "$f"; then
            echo "DID NOT COMMIT YOUR CHANGES!";
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is: the `.git` file structure:

- `.git/hooks/pre-commit`
- `.git/hooks/pre-commit-main.py`

.git/hooks/pre-commit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH="$THE_GOOD_PATH"
python "$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit-main.py"
```

.git/hooks/pre-commit-main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

Then, when you call `git commit`, make sure that `THE_GOOD_PATH`, is defined:

```
export THE_GOOD_PATH="$PATH"
git commit
```

You could also export `THE_GOOD_PATH="$PATH"` from your `.profile` or the toplevel of your application and symlink all hooks to a single file.

This method has the advantage of being virtualenv agnostic: it also works with Ruby RVM rbenv.

I wrote to the Git developers at: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/258454 asking them to leave our `PATH` alone, but the initial reply was WONTFIX.